# Can I create a github repository named the same as one that existed but was deleted?

Tags: github

Through the github web interface I created a new repository. I forgot to chose some options at creation time and thought I'd delete the new, empty repository and start again.

I deleted the repository but now cannot create a new repository with the same name as one that was deleted. I get a 'Name already exists on this account' error when I try.

I don't know if this is a permanent matter (i.e. I can never create a new repository named the same as one that has been deleted) or just a temporary matter perhaps due to some information being cached which will later be cleared.

Can I create a github repository named the same as one that existed but was deleted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You certainly should be able to create a new one with the same name. I'm fairly sure I've done this before.

I'd leave it for 5/10 minutes and try again if I were you.

Comment: Thanks Will. I'll indeed wait a bit and try again. It's good to know it's likely a caching matter and not a permanent matter.

Comment: I've given it quite a bit of time and still getting the same error. I'll see what github support say if this still happens in a day or two.

Comment: I've just run into this... any luck so far?

Comment: @David van Geest: no luck so far. A github android app I'm using lists 1 more repo than I have (the web interface doesn't) and includes in the list the 'deleted' repo. This suggests either deletion is buggy or metadata regarding repos for a user is not kept in sync all the time.

Comment: @DavidvanGeest Seems fine now, might have been a temporary issue with github as they're support said "It seems fine now. I am sorry for the trouble."

Comment: @JonCram thanks for the update.  Mine isn't working yet but I emailed support, and I imagine it will clear up.

Comment: What if you wanted to import an svn or other repo into an existing github repo! :( ?

Answer (score 16):

I faced this dilemma. But then I noticed I can rename a repo and then create a new repo with the old name, and in case there is a problem creating one with the old name, just rename the old one again...
So no need to delete the repo...

Comment: But, that's something to be done before the deletion.

Comment: Thanks, this was easy and worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue, using the Web interface, where the new repo creation page was saying the repo name was available, but I couldn't click the 'Create Repository' button. I opened the developer tools and removed the `disabled` attribute on the button. clicked again, and it just worked; could have tried to wait a bit and Ctrl+refresh the page, but I didn't want to loose the repository settings...

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this problem within the client interface (namely, the Windows client), you can refresh your repo list.  Once the repo in question disappears from the list, you should have no problem creating the new repo with the same name.

Answer (score -4):

I figured this one out. When you create a repo be sure the "publish to GitHub" is UNCHECKED. The problem is that it's trying to create a new repo on GitHub with the same name as the one you previously created there.

You should also consider going into your GitHub control panel and delete your old repo if it's not holding any information of value.